# WSO2 ESB + RabbitMQ Consumer: how to handle targets endpoint internal server errors

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB as RabbitMQ consumer: I have a proxy service which consumes messages from rabbit queue and sends it to my backend service using http endpoint.
Everything works fine and messages are successfully delivered to my backend.

The problem is that my backend service can fail sometimes and I would like to know about that fact and save this information in ESB log for example.

For example I would like to log `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` errors.

How can I achieve this?
I found out that I should use `FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT` property in my in sequence but it does not work in my case.

My consumer proxy configuration looks as follows:

```
<proxy name="AMQPProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="enable"
    trace="enable" transports="rabbitmq">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence onError="fault">
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT"
                scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="SampleEndPoint"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="MESSAGE" value="outSequence"/>
            </log>
            <drop/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.routing.key">route</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

How should I configure it to handle 5xx errors?

**Edit:**

I finally solve it using following proxy configuration:

```
<proxy name="AMQPProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="enable"
    trace="enable" transports="rabbitmq">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence onError="fault">
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="SampleEndPoint"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log>
                <property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="Status Code"/>
            </log>
            <filter regex="^((?!(200|202)).)*$" source="$axis2:HTTP_SC">
                <then>
                    <property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
                    <property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC_DESC" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
                    <sequence key="fault"/>
                </then>
            </filter>
            <drop/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.routing.key">route</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify you fault sequence to capture this information, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fault">
    <!-- Log the message at the full log level with the ERROR_MESSAGE and the ERROR_CODE-->
    <log level="full">
        <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured. Executing fault sequence"/>
        <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
        <property name="detail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
        <property name="exception" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
        <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
    </log>
    <!-- Drops the messages by default if there is a fault -->
    <drop/>
</sequence>
```

Also you may want to send a soap fault message to the client, so you can create a soapfault message and send it to the client in this way:

```
<makefault version="soap11">
    <code xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="tns:Receiver"/>
    <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
</makefault>
<send/>
<drop/>
```

Comment: I have fault sequence defined in my config. The problem is that the "fault" sequence is not called when my backend service responds with 500 error.

Comment: In this case the message hit the outsequence, so in this sequence you need to check for this type of error code and them take the proper actions. can you share the full log in the outsequence?

Comment: I finally solve it using your advice. There are two important thing to mention: you need to remove `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>` from `inSequence` (otherwise the `outSequence` will be not called) and you need to remove `Accept-Encoding` header from the message (otherwise WSO2 ESB will throw exception trying to parse that header value).  I updated my question with working configuration.